# source and destination must have equal size (8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I assume that the source and destination in MOV instruction must have the same size and when I write these instructions:

```
.data
var dw 0
.code
mov al,56h
mov var,al
```

I get the error that operands do not match 16-bit address and 8-bit register but in this condition, I don't get any error but still, var is 32 bit(double word) and ax is 16 bit so why I don't get any errors?

```
.data
var dd 0
.code
mov ax,56h
mov var,ax
```

I'm using emu 8086.

Comment: Which assembler do you use?

Comment: I could reproduce this behavior only on emu8086. MASM and TASM show the expected errors.

Comment: I'm using emu8086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8086 uses max 16 bit registers. When you tried to assign a 16 bit value to 32 bit variable, emu8086 assumes your variable is 16 bit.

Other assemblers that use the same syntax (MASM and TASM) do require an explicit `word ptr` size override if you want to store only the low word of a named location that you defined as a dword.  e.g. `mov word ptr [var], ax`.

For emu8086, you only need this when storing one byte into a word variable.

The MASM/TASM behaviour is more consistent with letting the symbol name imply a size when storing an immediate, like `mov var, 1` implies `word ptr` if you defined it with `dw`, even though there are no registers in the instruction to imply a size.